# Convert BigDecimal to cents

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

I want to convert a BigDecimal in Ruby to cents, here is what I did:

```
amount = BigDecimal('19.95')
#=> #<BigDecimal:7f80bc726b38,'0.1995E2',18(18)> 
amount_in_cents = amount*100
#=> #<BigDecimal:7f80bc794cc8,'0.1995E4',9(45)> 
amount_in_cents.to_f
#=> 1995.0
amount_in_cents.ceil
#=> 1995
```

So `ceil` gives me the right amount in cents, the amount I need to communicate to the payment provider. At the moment I'm not 100% sure if what I did here is correct. Maybe somebody knows a better way?

Comment: `ceil` moves towards positive infinity, `floor` towards negative infinity, `round` towards or away from zero depending on the fractional portion, and `to_i` simply truncates. Apply each of those four methods to `1.6`, `1.4`, `-1.6` and `-1.4` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `to_i`, which would communicate your intent even better, unless you expect to be dealing with fractional cents (in which case, `to_i` seems to truncate towards zero).